# Insert a string array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am scraping some data from a website. I have `names`, and `prices` lists from different pages. I want to stack two lists first, then an array contains all data in rows for each page. However, np.insert gives the following error:

> 'ValueError: could not convert string to float'.

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np

finallist = []
...
for c in range(0, 10)
    narr = np.array(names)
    parr = np.array(prices)

    nparr = np.array(np.column_stack((narr, parr)))

    finallist = np.insert(finallist, c, nparr)
```

What I want to accomplish is the following.

```
finallist =  [[[name1, price1], [name2, price3], ...] # from page one
               [name1, price1], [name2, price3], ...] # from page two
               ...                                  ] # from page x
```

So that I will be able reach all data.

Comment: Try setting dtype implicitly when creating arrays

Comment: How exactly can I do that?

Comment: If it is as following. Then it does not work.

    narr = np.array(names, dtype=str)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy array/matrix of mixed types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832715/numpy-array-matrix-of-mixed-types)

Comment: If you want to work with data like that you might want to try using `pandas`.

Comment: how about `finallist = np.insert(finallist, str(c), nparr)`?

Comment: No that gives more errors. I have amanged to solve the problem. I need to change `finallist=[]` into finallist=[''], so that array defined as string array. However I got another error on this line: 
`finallist = np.insert(finallist, c, nparr)`. It says conflicting shapes.