# declaring matrix as np.float32(np.array())

Tags: python, numpy

```
 matrix = np.float32(np.array([[0.0 for i in range(dimension)] for j in range(dimension)]))
```

If I want to do matrix operation in single precision, is the declaring array as above sufficient, or do I have to truncate for every arithmetic operation as follows?

```
np.float32(matrix[a][b] op matrix[c][d])
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can specify the `dtype` of the array:

```
np.array([[0.0 for i in range(dimension)] for j in range(dimension)],
         dtype=np.float32)
```

Note that if you work with zeros, you can also use:

```
np.zeros((dimension, dimension), dtype=np.float32)
```

By specifying `dtype`, *all* elements of the array have the same type. You can also specify the type of data if for instance *each* column has the same type, but the columns might differ, like is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833188/67579).