# Numpy array with mixed datatypes throwing "invalid literal for int() with base 10" for string

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a an array of mixed types with an int and string, but am getting an error when populating the string.

```
a = np.full(2, np.nan, dtype='u4,S10'
a[0] = 1
a[1] = b'abc'
```

And that gives me the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'abc'
```

Is there a way to have an array of mixed types that I can put byte arrays into like this?

Comment: Use `object` dtype : `np.full(2, np.nan, dtype=object)`.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832715/numpy-array-matrix-of-mixed-types

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign to a whole row.

Try:

```
a = np.full(2, np.nan, dtype='u4, S10')
a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 'abc'
```

Comment: So there isn't a way to make multiple datatypes in a 1-D array?

Comment: Use an `object` as dtype. It's the only way I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [246]: a = np.full(2, np.nan, dtype='u4,S10')
```

Look at the resulting array.  Note the `()` making the 2 records.  Also note that `np.nan` (a float) has been converted to other values according to the specified dtype (e.g. string 'nan'):

```
In [247]: a                                                                                          
Out[247]: array([(0, b'nan'), (0, b'nan')], dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', 'S10')])
```

Assigning 1 -  modifying both elements of the 1st record.  Again, note the string assignment:

```
In [248]: a[0] = 1                                                                                   
In [249]: a                                                                                          
Out[249]: array([(1, b'1'), (0, b'nan')], dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', 'S10')])
```

Access by field name:

```
In [250]: a['f0']                                                                                    
Out[250]: array([1, 0], dtype=uint32)
In [251]: a['f1']                                                                                    
Out[251]: array([b'1', b'nan'], dtype='|S10')
```

Modifying an element of the string field:

```
In [252]: a['f1'][1] = b'abc'                                                                        
In [253]: a                                                                                          
Out[253]: array([(1, b'1'), (0, b'abc')], dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', 'S10')])
```

Modifying both elements of a record - with a tuple:

```
In [254]: a[0] = (23, b'foobar')                                                                     
In [255]: a                                                                                          
Out[255]: 
array([(23, b'foobar'), ( 0, b'abc')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', 'S10')])
```

Initializing a structured array with a list of tuples:

```
In [256]: b = np.array([(2,b'xxx'),(34,b'xyz')], dtype=a.dtype)                                      
In [257]: b                                                                                          
Out[257]: array([( 2, b'xxx'), (34, b'xyz')], dtype=[('f0', '<u4'), ('f1', 'S10')])
```

All of this is documented:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#assigning-data-to-a-structured-array