# Providing dtypes for Dataframe.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

#### Problem description

When provided a func that returns a list of numerical values of different dtypes, DataFrame's *apply* up-converts all the returned values to a common type. For example, in the code below the elements in the 2nd column, the integers "3", are converted by the *apply()* to the complex number (3.0+0.0j).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df.apply(lambda row: [ 1+5j, 3], axis='columns', result_type='expand')

          0         1
0  1.0+5.0j  3.0+0.0j
1  1.0+5.0j  3.0+0.0j
2  1.0+5.0j  3.0+0.0j
```

This behavior is inherited from [Numpy's type determination](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array):

```
If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence.
```

Is there any way to provide a dtype parameter to the DataFrame's *apply* ?

Expected Output

```py
          0  1
0  1.0+5.0j  3
1  1.0+5.0j  3
2  1.0+5.0j  3
```

Comment: looks like it's the `expand` option that's doing this.  Without it, the result is 1 column with list elements.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to specify mixed dtypes within a numpy array, it seems the items have to be defined as a [tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832715/numpy-array-matrix-of-mixed-types):

```py
np.array((1+5j, 3), dtype='|complex, int')
```

So potential solutions include:

1. using `.astype({1: 'int'})`.
2. splitting real/imaginary and then recombining them as needed:

```py
df = df.apply(lambda row: [i for x in [ 1+5j, 3] for i in [x.real, x.imag]], axis='columns', result_type='expand')
df = df[df.columns[df.sum(axis=0)!=0]]
```